# Cluster thousands of text documents in java

Tags: performance, cluster-analysis, k-means

Is there efficient way clustering text documents? I thought about K-Means but it seems to be too time consuming. Can somebody provide me with an efficient method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If K-Means actually does the job, and simply seems to be slow, then why not try to make it faster? The method I use is [random-pausing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024).

It's usually the case that there is lots of room for speedup, in code you wouldn't have thought to be a problem, without changing the basic algorithm.
[Here's an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort/927773#927773)

Answer (score 1):

[clustering algorithm](http://home.dei.polimi.it/matteucc/Clustering/tutorial_html/) depends on your dataset  , do you want to write a algorithm in java to cluster your documents ?  , you can use [weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/) instead of reinvent the wheel and to try another clustering algorithm on your dataset .